# BottomNavigationView android rounded and scaled selected MenuItem

Tags: android, navbar, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to achieve something like this

[image: BottomNavBar Required]

I found lib that can help me make something similar but not the same.  https://github.com/tommybuonomo/morph-bottom-navigation

this is my usage for the library in xml layout:

```
    <com.tbuonomo.morphbottomnavigation.MorphBottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        style="?appBottomNavIcon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/transparent"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_text_color_state"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:textDirection="ltr"
        app:barrierDirection="start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:morphCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:morphItemRadius="64dp"
        app:morphVerticalOffset="16dp" />
```

and the design result is [image: BottomNavBar Completed]